# ember.js node and nginx

Tags: facebook, node.js, nginx, ember.js

I want to serve static webpages for a facebook application via nginx, enable interactivity via ember.js, and update pages with custom data via rest api on node.  Is this a logical set up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds perfect. Nginx is the fastest for serving files, Ember.js (or Backbone or JavaScriptMVC or Spine) is a good solution for your front-end JS structuring, and Node has a low memory footprint and is really fast (not to mention you can share code between front-end and back-end OR that you code is written in the same language everywhere, be it front-end or back-end).

I would suggest [Express.js](http://expressjs.com) for your REST stuff, it's a Sinatra inspired framework.

For other Node modules, [check here](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules).

Comment: thanks alessio, is express.js also appropriate for a public-facing api?

Comment: Sure, Express is used by Trello, Learnboost, Joyent and many others. It's the best Node.js web framework in my opinion and the oldest for sure.

Comment: In fact you should look at https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource for your REST.